# How to get null and filled values from database using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate to get data from oracle.I have Criterion object to make filter for hibernate select like this

```
Criterion cr6=null;
if(reqrrn != null)
            {
                cr6=Restrictions.eq("rrn", reqrrn);//o
            }
            else{
                cr6=Restrictions.like("rrn", "",MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
            }

Criterion cr20=null;
if(cardPrefix != null && cardPrefix != "")
            {
                cr20=Restrictions.eq("prefix", cardPrefix);
            }
            else{
                cr20=Restrictions.like("prefix", "",MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
            }
criteria.add(Restrictions.and(cr6, cr20));
```

i have filters like this, but it is usseless when value is null, for example
 cardPrefix value is null in database i want to get all values for cardPrefix ,which are filled and null too, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it. it will be for all parameters like

```
if(cardPrefix != null && cardPrefix != "")
            {
                cr20=Restrictions.eq("prefix", cardPrefix);
            }
            else{
                cr20=Restrictions.like("prefix", "",MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
                cr1=Restrictions.isNull("prefix");
                cr20=Restrictions.or(cr20, cr1);
            }
```